# Zuul not working with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, netflix-zuul

I am currently using zuul with different docker container. Everything works fine except for jenkins (not running inside a docker container). I want zuul to route to jenkins. This seems to work fine, but only for the main html page of jenkins, other files needed aren't loaded correctly. So when I open my page mypagename.com/jenkins the first request is send to the right address. But then the site tries to load the .css and .js files etc. "https://mypagename.com/static/9c0b28e1/css/layout-common.css". So for the first request zuul is working fine but for the following requests not.

The jenkins part of the application.yml looks like this:

`jenkins:
      path: /jenkins/**
      url: "http://172.21.0.1:9000/"`

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

It is now working. The root path for jenkins needed to be changed to /jenkins. Jenkins website root path. Also you need to restart jenkins after adding "--prefix=/jenkins" with something like "sudo systemctl restart jenkins" using the restart button on the jenkins website did not work.